# underscore.js Serverside

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, netsuite

We have an e-commerce site and all of the pages are being outputted using this javascript template engine _.template(). Most of the content on the site is unable to be read by search engines.

I tried to break/split the template so I can still get some content to be outputted server side but I run into issues where the server side code gets outputted before the template fully loads which causes the layout to break.

Is there a way to use server side code within the underscore.js template (if that makes sense.) I can't make the entire section server side that's going to open a whole other can of worms as well(we use netsuite).

Any ideas will help.

Comment: How is underscore.js a "template" and how are search engines unable to read web pages that use it?

Comment: http://techslides.com/javascript-templating-frameworks-and-seo

Comment: @AAA Likely referring to [`_.template()`](http://underscorejs.org/#template) and client-side generated content. Many search engines don't execute JavaScript to be able to crawl that content.

Comment: correct Jonathan i've added to the original description with the terminology you used. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't assume that search engines aren't indexing your content. Both [Google](http://www.rimmkaufman.com/blog/googlebot-crawling-javascript-site-ready/03062014/) and [Bing](http://ajax.rswebanalytics.com/seo-for-ajax/#!searchbot_differences_for_indexing_ajax_content), for example, will execute JavaScript during their site crawling. If your content isn't getting indexed, make sure you're following the search engines' [various](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html) [guidelines](http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/help-center-661b2d18).

As to your specific question, it is certainly *possible* to execute Underscore on the server side. That's clearly easiest if your server technology is JavaScript (e.g. Node.js or io.js), but there are versions of Underscore for [other](https://rubygems.org/gems/underscore-rails) [languages](http://brianhaveri.github.io/Underscore.php/). Just because it's possible, though, doesn't mean it's desirable. Presumably there's some reason your site is using client-side templates. Perhaps, for example, the data required to render the templates is only available on the client. If that's the case, you'll find it challenging to replicate the required functionality on the server side. Whatever the implementation, it's almost certainly not going to be an easy or trivial change.

Comment: I've looked and crawlers are not indexing the pages. I understand the reason that they used these templates which might be hard to explain unless you are familiar with netsuite. I'm able to do serverside scripting but the serverside text or whatever display before the entire (template) page renders.